# Managing environment variables in arcpy?

Tags: python, arcpy, environment-variable

The Arcpy documentation seems to suggest that when writing python scripts that utilize/modify variables in `arcpy.env`, you should wrap everything in a bunch of `try/except/(finally)` loops with custom error types (which are generally a bad practice, IMO).

In the case [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//010300000306000000), they don't even guard against errors leaving the extension checked out:

```
import arcpy
import arcpyproduction

# Check out Production Mapping license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Foundation")

# Define map document, data frame, and polygon geometry coordinates
[snip]

# Create polygon geometry
for coordPair in coordList:
    x, y = coordPair.split(";")
    pnt = arcpy.Point(x,y)
    array.add(pnt)
array.add(array.getObject(0))
boundaryPolygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)

[snip]

# Check in extension
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Foundation")
```

I know that's not a huge risk, but there's got to be a better way, right?

Comment: For the curious, [yes, you can post a question that you know the answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current versions of ArcGIS Desktop and Pro have the [`arcpy.EnvManager`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/classes/envmanager.htm)

Previously you had to use context managers. In particular, I have three for

- `arcpy.env.workspace`,
- `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput`, and
- `arcpy.Check[In|Out]Extension`

[They are](https://gist.github.com/phobson/b3078602db48fbe5bd49):

```
class Extension(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        if arcpy.CheckExtension(self.name) == "Available":
            arcpy.CheckOutExtension(self.name)
        else:
            raise ValueError("%s license isn't available" % self.name)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        arcpy.CheckInExtension(self.name)
            

class OverwriteState(object):
    def __init__(self, overwrite):
        self.orig_state = arcpy.env.overwriteOutput
        self.new_state = bool(overwrite)

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = self.new_state

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = self.orig_state


class WorkSpace(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.orig_workspace = arcpy.env.workspace
        self.new_workspace = path

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arcpy.env.workspace = self.new_workspace

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arcpy.env.workspace = self.orig_workspace
```

If your version of arcpy is recent enough to be on Python 2.7, you can use them all at the same time like this:

```
with Extension("3D"), OverwriteState(True), Workspace("c:/GrosMorne"):
    arcpy.HillShade_3d("WesternBrook", "wbrook_hill", 300)
    arcpy.Aspect_3d("WesternBrook", "wbrook_aspect")
```

If you're stuck on Python 2.6, it's a little uglier:

```
with Extension("3D"):
    with OverwriteState(True):
        with: Workspace("c:/GrosMorne"):
            arcpy.HillShade_3d("WesternBrook", "wbrook_hill", 300)
            arcpy.Aspect_3d("WesternBrook", "wbrook_aspect")
```

These guard against errors in whatever processing you do so that the environment variables/extensions are reverted back to their original state no matter how the code within the `with` block exits (e.g., successfully, errored, interrupted).

That looks something like this:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False
print('Before the context manager: {}'.format(arcpy.env.overwriteOutput))
with OverwriteState(True):
    print('Inside the context manager: {}'.format(arcpy.env.overwriteOutput))
    raise ValueError("arcpy is a bad time")
print('After the context manager: {}'.format(arcpy.env.overwriteOutput))
```

Output:

```
Before the context manager: False
Inside the context manager: True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
[snip]
ValueError: arcpy is a bad time
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
After the context manager: False
```

---

After learning about some python standard library goodness, the context managers simplify to:

```
import arcpy
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def Extension(name):
    """ Safely use ArcGIS extensions """
    if arcpy.CheckExtension(name) == u"Available":
        status = arcpy.CheckOutExtension(name)
        yield status
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("%s license isn't available" % name)

    arcpy.CheckInExtension(name)


@contextmanager
def OverwriteState(state):
    """ Temporarily set the ``overwriteOutput`` env variable. """
    orig_state = arcpy.env.overwriteOutput
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = bool(state)
    yield state
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = orig_state


@contextmanager
def WorkSpace(path):
    """ Temporarily set the ``workspace`` env variable. """
    orig_workspace = arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = path
    yield path
    arcpy.env.workspace = orig_workspace
```

Comment: I really like this context manager-based approach - I had some functions I was using to get the same results, but this is more elegant. I wanted it generic though, so I wrote a context manager for all of the environment settings. https://gist.github.com/nickrsan/74461397d9af015db3879c7d2e5f3227#gistcomment-2111123 - it seemed like enough of a shift that I shouldn't edit it into the answer though, but thought it was worth leaving here. Thanks for the great idea!

Comment: @nicksan -- I think that's a great approach and totally belongs in this answer! I posted it as a wiki for a reason ;)